# Setting up a LAMP server that doesn't log/store IP addresses?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, lamp, privacy

What kind of configurations would need to be made to a basic Ubuntu LAMP installation to prevent it from logging visitors IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the CustomLog directive in your apache config:

```
fgrep -wir CustomLog /etc/apache2/
```

You will find something like this:

```
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log vhost_combined
```

Look for the third part, `combined` and `vhost_combined` are nicknames for `LogFormat`s. They are defined inside `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` with the [LogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) directive, containing several [Format Strings](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats).

Look for

```
%a  Remote IP-address
%h  Remote host
```

and remove them from your `LogFormat` directives. It might be smarter to replace them with `0.0.0.0` so log file processing can still take place.

Before:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

After:

```
LogFormat "0.0.0.0 %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html

```
Syntax:     LogFormat format|nickname [nickname]
Default:    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"
```

Don't use %h or %a